# Page level custom variables not showing in Google Analytics dashboard

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have the following tracking script that is being executed but I dont see the custom variables in slot 2,3 and 4 show up on the Google analytics dashboard under Demographics -> Custom Variables. However I do see the custom variable for slot 1 appear on the dashboard.

Are there any restrictions when there are custom variables of different scopes in the same tracking script?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var _gaq = _gaq || [];
   _gaq.push(['_setAccount','UA-XXXXXXX-X']);
   _gaq.push(['_setCookiePath','/shop']);
   _gaq.push(['_setDomainName','.XXXXX.com']);
   _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker',true]);
   _gaq.push(['_setAllowHash',false]);
   _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'customerAccount','xxxxx',1]);
   _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',2,'SKU ID | SKU NAME','0116516 | X-9 COPY PAPER 8.5X11" RM WE',3]);
   _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',3,'CATEGORY ID','2 | 368 | 1602',3]);
   _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',4,'CATEGORY NAME','MULTI-USE COPY PAPER',3]);
   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
   (function() {
       var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
       ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
     var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
```

I verified the script via Firebug in Firefox and do see the _utm.gif request fired and the utme param seems to have the custom variable values for all the slots.

Its been about 4 days since the tracking script was executed but still no values on the dashboard for custom variables 2,3,4.  Any help will be appreciated as to why the
page level custom variables don't show up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure, but I think your Pipe Symbol (|) and your double quotes (") might screw-up with your tracking.

Oh and _setAllowHash() is deprecated and no longer required for cross-domain tracking.

## edit1:

This might be a better option for you as it seems you are tracking sales.
http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingEcommerce.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked the Google Analytics API for custom variables but dont see any limitations around special characters like Pipe or double quotes.  I am going to try replacing the special characters to see if it makes a difference. Also thanks for the tip on _setAllowHash and I will be removing that.

Comment: Are you still haveing issues?

Comment: Yes , still having issues . I tried several options - removing cookies , replacing special characters and still the page level custom variables noted in the original post didn't show up.

I changed the scope for custom variables 2,3,4 to visitor level and was able to see the values show up in GA under Demographics -> Custom Variables. Note that the special characters was left as such during this test and it showed up as expected on the Analytic dashboard.

Could it be any special settings on my GA account ? Do page level custom variables show up in a different section of the GA dashboard?

Comment: Ah yes, the scope set to 3..
The Custom variables data can be integrated in 3 different report types:1The Custom Variables report (in the Visitors section in the main menu) 2The “Advanced Segments” 3The “Custom Reports”
_trackEvent shows up @ Content -> Events

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Could you please elaborate on where the Custom Variables report is in the Visitor section? I was expecting the page level custom variables to show up under Demographics -> Custom Variables section.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I was thinking about the old version.
Anyways, under tab custom reports you can add the data as a dimension.
That would be the easyest way to look at the data.

Comment: Thanks @ErikdR. I do see the page level custom variables when I create a Custom Report and add the custom vars as dimension.  Is it wrong to expect Page level custom variables to appear under Demographics -> Custom Variables?

Comment: Yes, they will not apear there.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @ErikdR. Is this documented anywhere in the Google Analytics API?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Took days to resolve.

The reason is this: To view *Page level custom variables*, you'll need to specify explicitly the **metric** and **dimensions**, which can be done via the **Custom Report** (click the Customization tab).

The default dashboard will not show *page level custom variable* values. Here's a screenshot of my custom report configuration for custom variable of slot 2:

[image: Page Level Custom Variable]